# Query across all versions of a table in a Multi-tenant separate schema database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

In a multi tenant SQL Server database where there are multiple copies of tables with the same names, with each copy of the table belonging to a different schema, is there any way to query across all copies of the table without a `union`?

Something like:

```
select * from *.TABLE_NAME
```

I'm fairly sure the answer is no, and googling suggests that's the case, but I'm wondering if such a thing is possible?  I appreciate that potentially the tables might have different columns.

Comment: If the table schemas are the same, you might be able to simulate this using   remote linked server tables, and a view on top of these.. but you would have to do the `union` in the view.. so don't think you can avoid the `union`

Comment: Assuming you have a known set of columns that are "guaranteed" to be consistent you could utilize some dynamic sql to make this fairly simple. But you will have to either have a (temp)table or use a union for this to work.

Comment: Begin with the notion that no such thing exists. They are not 'copies', they simply happen to have the same name. but as far as the objects go, they are completely unrelated and independent objects. In short, the answer is: No.

Comment: Absolutely @RicardoC, I wouldn't expect this to be a part of ANSI SQL, more a convenience function added to SQL server or something along those lines

Comment: @tomRedox Similar convenience does exist, not as part of SQL Server but provided by Management Studio. You can run a single query over multiple connections (registered servers). Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@tomReddox

See if this helps. This can be easily coded inside a Stored Proc and called everytime by simply exec SP_Name instead of the lengthy sp_MSforeachtable command below.

```
-- Create a Schema for demonstration
CREATE SCHEMA [SCH1] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

-- Create Table in Schema1 (= SCH1 )
create table [SCH1].TEST ( C1 int )
insert into  [SCH1].TEST values ( 1 ) 

-- Create Table in Schema2 ( = dbo )
create table dbo.TEST ( C1 int )
insert into  dbo.TEST values ( 2 ) 
insert into  dbo.TEST values ( 3 ) 

--  Create Results Table in dbo schema this will hold the results
Create Table dbo.Res ( C1 int ) -- Results Table that holds the union of all the *.TEST Tables. Make sure you name it anything other than Test !!


-- Use the sp_MSforeachtable command with the  @whereand  clause to filter only the TEST tables. 
-- This sp searches all schemas in the DB. must use alias for name as o.name
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1='insert into dbo.RES select *  from ? ' 
     ,  @whereand = ' AND o.name LIKE ''TEST%'' ' 
     ,  @postcommand = ' select  * from dbo.Res '
Go
```